# How to remove required from Django-Widget-Tweaks form field

Tags: django, django-widget-tweaks

I am trying to remove the required attribute from a django-widget-tweaks form.

I tried:

```
{% render_field form.legal_entity|attr:'required:false' placeholder=form.legal_entity.label class+="form-control" %}
```

and

```
{% render_field form.legal_entity|remove_attr:"required" placeholder=form.legal_entity.label class+="form-control" %}
```

No matter what I do, the result is always:

```
<input type="text" name="legal_entity" maxlength="120" class="form-control" placeholder="Firmenname" required id="id_legal_entity">
```

Here is the according Form:

```
class MerchantForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = ['name', 'legal_entity', 'legal_address','legal_zip', 'legal_city','address', 'zip', 'city', 'contact_person', 'phone', 'email']

 def clean_legal_entity(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['legal_entity']
        return data
```

...

Comment: Can you share the Django form?

Comment: See the edit of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the field as non-required by setting [**`required=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#required) in the corresponding field:

```
class MerchantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    legal_entity = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = ['name', 'legal_entity', 'legal_address','legal_zip', 'legal_city','address', 'zip', 'city', 'contact_person', 'phone', 'email']
```

Answer (score 1):

in the JS code of your HTML page:

```
 window.onload=myfunction();
 function myfunction()
{
    $("input").removeAttr("required");
    $("select").removeAttr("required");
    $("textarea").removeAttr("required");
}
```